# Ответ при не удовлетворительных данных

Tags: php, http

Подскажите как ответить на неверные данные, каким сообщением и статусом.

```
      if (!empty($params['user_login']) && !empty($params['user_password'])) {

        $login = trim($params['user_login']);
        $password = trim($params['user_password']);

        if(strlen($login) >= 4 && strlen($login) <= 10 
          && strlen($password) >= 6 && strlen($password) <= 20) {

          // код который реализует регистрацию

          if (// проверка на успешность регистрации) {
            $data = [
              'signup' => 'success'
            ];

            return $res->withStatus(201)
              ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
              ->write(json_encode($data));
          } else {
            $data = [
              'signup' => 'failed'
            ];

            return $res->withStatus(200)
              ->withHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
              ->write(json_encode($data));
          }

        } else {
          // как ответить если данные не верны, коротки или длинные.
          // какой статус для этого использовать
        }

      } else {
        // как ответить если данные не верны, логин или пароль пуст.
        // какой статус использовать 
      }
```

Comment: Статус по вашему усмотрению из 4xx/5xx, например `500 Internal Server Error`.

Comment: `400 bad request` вам чем-то не подходит?

Comment: @teran Нет. Я только разбираюсь в этом, и не совсем понятно как действовать в каких ситуация.

Comment: если это у вас форма регистрации и вы просто хотите пользователю ответить, что пароль слишком короткий и т.п. то отдавайте 200 ОК, с нужным контентом и все. Запрос ведь обработан успешно в данном случае.

Comment: @teran Да форма, на front end, AJAX запрос.  А какой message передать для проверки на front end? Отдавать Login or password is too long  и проверять на эту строку, кажется слишком. Возможно есть где-то рекомендации по этому поводу, или специально заводить code для проверки, по примеру как у ВК, и прописать доку для это. Есть вообще ресурсы с рекомендация как правильно писать api, так сказать best practices?

Comment: Проверка на максимальную длинну пароля это ваше личное дело, я бы не делал. Но тримить пароль, это как минимум странно. Пользователь может специально пробел хочет, как часть пороля.

Comment: передайте в ответе что нить вида `{ success: false, errors: [{ field: 'login', msg: "логин занят"}, { ... еще ошибки } ]}`.то что надо то и передайте. сформулируйте мысль свою корректно да и все.